# How to make a reverse Foreign Key in multiple tables with annotate

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 models connected to one by a Foreign Key:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_b = models.FloatField()

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_c = models.FloatField()

class D(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_d = models.FloatField()
```

And I want to make a JOIN query based on the foreign keys using Django ORM to get the sum of each amount.

In SQL I would make something like:

```
SELECT 
  a.name, 
  b_sum,
  c_sum,
  d_sum
FROM A AS a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.a, sum(amount_b) as b_sum
              from B as b
              group by b.a) as AB AB.a = a.id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT c.a, sum(amount_c) as c_sum
              from C as c
              group by a) AS AC ON AC.a = a.id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT d.a, sum(amount_d) as d_sum
              from D as d
              group by a) AS AD ON AD.a = a.id
WHERE a.name LIKE 'init%'
```

But I didn't find something like that on django ORM.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this

```
q = A.objects.annotate(
    b_sum=Subquery(
        B.objects.filter(a=OuterRef('pk'))
                 .values('a')
                 .annotate(b_sum=Sum('amount_b'))
                 .values('b_sum')
    ),
    c_sum=Subquery(
        C.objects.filter(a=OuterRef('pk'))
                 .values('a')
                 .annotate(c_sum=Sum('amount_c'))
                 .values('c_sum')
    ),
    d_sum=Subquery(
        D.objects.filter(a=OuterRef('pk'))
                 .values('a')
                 .annotate(d_sum=Sum('amount_d'))
                 .values('d_sum')
    )
)
```

It seems pretty complex query and also does not translate to same sql you mentioned in question, but it does the job.

Here is sql it generates.

```
SELECT "A"."id",
       "A"."name",
       (SELECT SUM(U0."amount_b") AS "b_sum" FROM "B" U0 WHERE U0."a_id" = ("A"."id") GROUP BY U0."a_id") AS "b_sum",
       (SELECT SUM(U0."amount_c") AS "c_sum" FROM "C" U0 WHERE U0."a_id" = ("A"."id") GROUP BY U0."a_id") AS "c_sum",
       (SELECT SUM(U0."amount_d") AS "d_sum" FROM "D" U0 WHERE U0."a_id" = ("A"."id") GROUP BY U0."a_id") AS "d_sum"
FROM "A"
```

Comment: That's what I needed! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you find your query to be complex for DJango ORM then there are ways to execute raw queries directly.

```
>>> for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
...     print(p)
John Smith
Jane Jones
```

This code snippet is picked from DJango site itself.
Complete URL is as follows.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/

The link given also contains custom query options and cursors etc to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`B.amount_b` and `D.amount_d` are `CharField`s, performing a sum on those fields could cause issues if they do not contain numeric values. You should consider changing them to numeric fields

Something like the following would give you a queryset of A objects annotated with those sums

```
queryset = A.objects.annotate(
    b_sum=Sum('b__amount_b'),  # It's either "b" or "b_set"
    c_sum=Sum('c__amount_c'),
    d_sum=Sum('c__amount_d'),
)
for a in queryset:
    print(a.name, a.b_sum, a.c_sum, a.d_sum)
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to change the fields on model to FloatField.

I'll try this.

Comment: It didnt't works :'(

I already have tried something like this before.
Thanks anyway.